# In Excel I am wondering how if a value is met in a column then to sum up the cell to the left of that value across multiple rows if that makes sense

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

For example where the cell says David I want to sum all the cells on the left of David in £ up to a total like at the bottom not sure how I'd go about this.

```
     £4500      IWI      14/12    DAVID
     £3200      EAH      13/12    CRAIG
     £8600      IWI      17/12    JOHN
     £6300      IWI      16/12    DAVID
     £7800      IWI      14/12    DAVID
```

DAVID TOTAL =
JOHN TOTAL =
CRAIG TOTAL =

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post with what you have tried so far. If you haven't tried anything yet, please take a look at pivot tables or the `SUMIF` function.

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIF()` is what you need here.

Your IF test column is the fourth one, call it column D, where the names are. Your column to sum is the first one, call it column A, where the values are. So, for the data set above, taking a name you enter in cell E5, this formula gives you your   desired result:

```
=SUMIF(D1:D5,  "="&E1,  A1:A5)
```

If you'd like to sum up for all the unique names in column D, you could do:

```
=SUMIF(D1:D5,"="&UNIQUE(D1:D5),A1:A5)
```

(You'd likely want another column, the names(!) to its left, say, and would populate that with just:

```
=UNIQUE(D1:D5)
```

in which case you might prefer to link/lock them by referring to that list of results rather than having `UNIQUE()` in your `SUMIF()`:

```
=SUMIF(D1:D5,"="&E1#,A1:A5)
```

if the list of unique names is in column E and you have `SPILL` functionality available. If not, address the range literally, or don't link/lock the columns together:  it's not necessary for accuracy, now, just in the future if there are changes.